# Git on Windows 8: "git-pull is broken?" error

Tags: windows-8, git

When I run 'git pull' from TortoiseGit on my Windows 8 machine, I get the following error:

fatal: 'pull' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-pull is broken?

I have found someone else who had this error. They resolved it by uninstalling/reinstalling Git. I tried that and it did not work. I also uninstalled/reinstalled TortoiseGit. Nothing helps. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: have you installed msysgit?

Comment: yes. I just intalled v1.8.3 and I still get the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17813141/238419

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Cygwin installed on your machine? If so try selecting "Use Git bash only" in "Adjusting your ENV. Path" windows